# Enable MFA in SSO Sandbox login

Tags: single-sign-on, mfa

I am trying to enable MFA in SSO sandbox login, but while login into the sandbox it is not asking for any authentication. It is working in the case, when I am login without SSO. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Using MFA in combination with SSO requires a separate setting, as described in the [salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfa_sso_logins.htm&type=5)

> To set up the Salesforce MFA service, take these steps.
>
> 1. In Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Session, then select Session Settings.
> 2. In Session Security Levels, make sure your SSO configuration is in the Standard column. And make sure Multi-Factor Authentication is in
>    the High Assurance column.
> 3. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Profiles, then select Profiles.
> 4. Click the profile name, then click Session Settings in the System section.
> 5. Click Edit, set Session Security Level Required at Login to High Assurance, then save your changes.

Comment: It's not clear whether the question refers to Salesforce's MFA or another form of MFA SSO. In the case of another identity provider, these instructions are not correct.

Comment: If the other provider is a different salesforce org, it is correct. If it's not a salesforce org they shouldn't ask the question in the salesforce stack exchange but refer to the documentation of whatever else they're using.